# What MySQL drivers are available for node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, node.js

Is there a Node.JS Driver for MySQL that is commonly used other than [node-mysql?](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)

(It seems like there is not much activity with node.js database drivers. Is there a reason for this or is it just because Node.JS is so young?)

Comment: Can this please be reopened. While determining which driver is best might be subjective, it is a very good list of drivers, probably the best compilation on the web. Besides, this page ranks first on Google when you search for "node.js mysql".

Comment: This is a useful question. Should be reopened.

Comment: Sometimes debate is actually useful.  What better way to find out the pros and cons of various options?  Please reopen. If this really isn't a good fit for your format, perhaps you should consider expanding the format.

Comment: Great question. Visitors get to see opinions of experts that hang around on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please reopen, this is constructive and is bringing a lot of users in-search of answers.

Comment: I'd like to see this one reopened as well.  In a lot of cases, these questions fly off the handle, but this one has been particularly constructive.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377722/most-mature-native-node-js-mysql-driver and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345090/what-is-the-most-mature-stable-mysql-node-js-module for listings of node mysql modules

Comment: No. No it cannot be re-opened. This is a useful post. Why would we ever re-open a question if it helps you? It's our new business model. Also, remember to save up money for our pay wall coming up soon.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are some options:

- http://github.com/felixge/node-mysql (last update: Sep 29th)
- https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2 (last update: Sep 04, 2018)

Comment: I decided to go with piscisaureus' branch of node-mysql. It looks good so far! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can also try out a newer effort known as [Node.js DB](http://nodejsdb.org/) that aims to provide a common framework for several database engines. It is built with C++ so performance is guaranteed.

Specifically you could use its db-mysql driver for [Node.js MySQL support](http://nodejsdb.org/db-mysql).

Comment: Node.js DB is platform dependent, so it doesn't work on e.g. Windows.

Comment: "It is built with C++ so performance is guaranteed".  Ha ha.

Answer (score 5):

Just look at https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient.

Comment: Is it possible to run asynchronous DML statements? For example, I want to run a bunch of UPDATEs and DELETEs async.

Comment: Yes of course. You should use `conn.query()` for this.

Answer (score 5):

If you need an ORM for MySQL you might want to check out http://sequelizejs.com :)

Answer (score 3):

For connecting to MySQL with node.js, I've had great success using [node-odbc](https://github.com/w1nk/node-odbc)

It's also worked flawlessly for connecting to other databases such as IBM's DB2, and it's been surprisingly fast.

[This page](http://www.webaj.com/how-setup-mysql-dsn-datasbase-source-centos-myodbc-and-unixodbc-command-line.htm) is particularly useful for configuring ODBC on linux.

After installing with `yum install mysql-connector-odbc`, my /etc/odbc.ini file looks like this:

```
[MYSQL]
Description = MySQL ODBC Driver
Driver      = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc3.so
```

I left out stuff such as server, user, database, port, password etc. so that I can set these from my connection string (I need to connect to multiple databases).

After saving /etc/odbc.ini, it's installed with this command: `odbcinst -i -s -l -f /etc/odbc.ini`

And here's a code sample for testing it out:

```
    var odbc = require("odbc");
    var db = new odbc.Database();
    var conn = "dsn=mysql;server=localhost;user=root;database=mydb;port=3306;password=mypwd;command timeout=30000;";
    db.open(conn, function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        var params = ['jiy@stackoverflow.com'];
        var qry = "select * users where email = ?";
        db.query(qry, params, function(err, rows, def) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log(rows);
        });
    });
```

Or if you wanted to use coffeescript:

```
    odbc = require "odbc"
    db = new odbc.Database()
    conn = "dsn=mysql;server=localhost;user=root;database=mydb;port=3306;password=mypwd;command timeout=30000;"

    db.open conn, (err) ->
        throw err if err

        qry = "select * from users where email = ?"

        db.query sql, ["jiy@stackoverflow.com"], (err, rows, def) ->
            if err? then console.log err else
            console.log rows
```