# Node.js - connect to MySQL database server

Tags: php, mysql, database, node.js

I got server A, which is a node.js server, and server B which is apache php server. I want to know how I can use server A to get data from database on server B. Is there a module or middleware which can do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878818/node-js-and-mysql-drivers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can connect [remotely](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) to server B with [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) module by setting client `host`, `port`, `user` and `password` options (see tutorial and API of node-mysql).