# What is the most mature/stable mysql node.js module

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am looking to do some work around mysql and node.js and have found a few different modules out there but I cannot get a good bead on their stability/maturity. I know each author puts very hard work into each one, but for the work we're doing I need to know I've got a solid mysql foundation. The modules I've found that look pretty good are:

1. [db-mysql](https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/) This appears pretty active.
2. [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) This is a pretty pervasive module I've seen so far, it appears to be in a maintenance phase, and seems solid.
3. [node-mysql-native](https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native) I like the async work being done here, but I'm not sure how well it works yet.
4. [node-mysql-libmysqlclient](https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient) I'm not sure about this one, but it appears to be active as well.

I don't have many needs that are too far out of the ordinary. I need regular query support, extras would be nice, I just need a good foundation to start from. Any input as to the strengths and weaknesses of these modules would be great. If there is another quality contender I have not found I am not at all against considering another option.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm the author of node-mysql-native driver, from my point of view the differences are

1. no prepared statements support (yet) in node-mysql
2. according to my benchmarks node-mysql is 10-20% slower than node-mysql-native
3. node-mysql has much wider adoption, more tests and users. If you need stability, better use it
4. node-mysql-libmysqlclient is 2 to 3 times faster on fast queries. However, if you have a lot of slow queries and use connection pools it could be even slower than native JS driver because libmysqlclient async calls are based on nodejs thread pool and not on event loop.

*update*

As of 11/07/2013

- (2). no longer valid (mysql-native is a bit slower than node-mysql)
- have [this alternative](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) to node-mysql, on some benchmarks it's 2-3 times faster, has same API + support for prepared statements, SSL and compression. Also implements simple subset of server side protocol - see for example [MySQL -> Postgres proxy](https://github.com/sidorares/mysql-pg-proxy).
- [node-mariasql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql/) is also a very good option (if it's ok to use binary addon) - fast, stable, async, prepared statements support, compression and SSL.

Comment: Thanks for the information Andrey, this gives me a little more to think about.

Comment: 1 - true, 2 - no longer true (node-mysql faster than mysql-native), 3 - true, 4 - true (but now it's easier to change thread pool size - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/U06-jUFlvW4/_3T-kqrqIagJ ) 5 - copule of month ago I created https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2 which is API compatible with node-mysql + speed & extras like compression, prepared statements and SSL. 6) Worth taking a look at https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql/ (binary, fast, prepared statements)

Answer (score 7):

I went through a similar search and ended up settling on node-mysql. I like it's simplicity, the fact that it's pure js, and that it's well supported. It was slower in tests that I did than some of the mixed modules (those that used non-js libs), but I did a minor patch that helped considerably with that for my cases:

https://github.com/geochap/node-mysql

Comment: Thanks Geoff, thanks for the information about your fork, I'll have to give it a look.

Comment: Please note the github page @Geoff is reffering to is outdated (1000+ commits behind). Use: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql