# Is it Possible to retrieve Database data using client-side code?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can JavaScript connect with MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql)

I have a database with names and emails. When the user fills a email input field with a email. JS checks it with the database and writes out persons name after he completed the email in the field.

`joe@exampl.com`    Welcome John Doe!

Is it Possible to retrieve  MySQL Database data using JavaScript?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fortunately, JavaScript doesn't have direct access to the database. Otherwise, it was was a godsend for hackers. It only has access to resources located on the client side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a typical browser environment (since you specify client side code), no, and it would be insane to expose the database in a way that would grant a browser such permissions if it were possible.

Write a web service that the browser can interact with by using Forms or Ajax to make HTTP requests instead.

(Aside: If you hadn't specified client side, then [node js can do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878818/node-js-and-mysql-drivers)).

Answer (score 0):

No. For doing such a thing, you need a server for that. What you could do, if the database resides on the same machine as the client, is using [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/), giving you a means of accessing a local DB (which is a NoSQL-DB).